# Specific need for tcp/ip routing with iptables

Tags: iptables, routing, openvpn, ipsec

I would like to do the following thing:

- One server with public IP (say `1.2.3.4`) and internal IP (say `192.168.1.1`)
- Multiple VPN routers connecting (IPSEC and OPENVPN) (port 500/1194/4500)
- Internal VPN Linux servers (`192.168.1.2`->`192.168.1.100` for example)

I would like this :

- Connection from specific IP (e.g. `5.6.7.8`) arrives on IPSEC and OPENVPN incoming portsand packets are redirected to -> `192.168.1.2` (to other ports maybe?)
- Connection from anotherIP (e.g. `8.9.10.11`) arrives on IPSEC and OPENVPN incoming ports and packets are redirected to -> `192.168.1.3`  (to other ports maybe?)

and so on...

1. Is it feasible? I have searched a lot, but didn't come up with an answer.
2. If it is, how to do it with `iptables`?

Answer (score 0):

It is feasible. I do not know, if you have already running iptables with all the policies, etc. So I will write only the lines to add what you are looking for to a working routing station placed between intranet and internet. Only these two lines alone will not work.

Try something like this:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s 5.6.7.8 -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 500 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.2:500
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 5.6.7.8 -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 500 -j SNAT --to-source <ip of iptables computer>
```

The first line changes the destination to your internal server, so the packets are sent to the right destination. The second line changes the source, so that the server knows where to send the packets back.

Comment: Hi, does it mean I need to masquerade packets also (on output)